# Displaying arrow using spplot and sp.layout

Tags: r, sp

I have been wrestling with an error (that I am clearly making) in trying to add an arrow on the bottom right of an otherwise functional sp plot. I am using sp.layout and a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

The dimensions are: xmin, 29.122917, xmax, 29.20292, ymin, -3.445416, ymax, -3.33875 The

Here is my code:

```
north <- list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), 
              offset = c(29.15, -3.44), scale = 500)

spplot(population_raster100mshp, 
       scales=list(draw = TRUE), 
       lwd=0, par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")), cex.main=0.8,
       sp.layout = list(north))
```

This produces the plot and axes, but no arrow. I have tried moving around the offset, but it does not appear at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hard to help without knowing what `population_raster100mshp` is. Your line that starts "The dimension is" seems cut off. What does `summary` of that object tell us?

Comment: Thanks as always @Spacedman. It is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, specifically:                                                                                                
                                                                                                                  > 
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min      max
x 29.122083 29.20542
y -3.447083 -3.33875
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string : [+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scale of 500 is way too big for your lat-long degree data.

Simplifying a bit, and with a `population_raster100mshp` which is two points at your bounding box limits with a Z value for colouring:

```
north = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), 
              offset = c(29.15, -3.44), scale =.010)
spplot(population_raster100mshp,"Z",sp.layout=list(north))
```

[image]

Comment: The scale was the issue. Thank you for your insights!